# SSH restart and kill instances?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to restart SSH on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

but this just gives me:

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
>   utility, e.g. service ssh restart

However, running that gives:

> restart: Unknown instance:

Running:

```
ps -A | grep ssh
```

gives 3 instances.

**Question**

How do I tell which is my instance, and kill the others? Will this then allow me to restart?

Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Invoking the init.d script should still restart the service:

```
dermot@porkboy:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
[sudo] password for dermot:
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service ssh restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop ssh ; start ssh. The restart(8) utility is also available.
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 4877
dermot@porkboy:~$
```

'service ssh restart' works fine here (11.04). It's worth noting that restarting sshd **won't kill existing SSH sessions**. When you log into a box via SSH, sshd spawns new processes to handle the session. Restarting sshd will kill the main sshd daemon process (and start it again, obviously) but leave other spawned instances of sshd untouched. You want this behaviour because it makes life a lot easier when you're working with headless servers in distant datacenters!

Now, to answer the rest of your question. Instead of running 'ps -A', try this:

```
dermot@porkboy:~$ ps -ef | grep ssh
root      2522     1  0 Aug29 ?        00:00:00 sshd: dermot [priv]
dermot    2615  2522  0 Aug29 ?        00:00:04 sshd: dermot@pts/0
root      4655     1  0 10:52 ?        00:00:00 sshd: dermot [priv]
dermot    4756  4655  0 10:52 ?        00:00:00 sshd: dermot@pts/1
root      4887     1  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

This probably accounts for the three sshd processes you're seeing - one for the main sshd daemon and then two (root parent, dermot child) per session. I'm SSHed in from two locations o I have five processes. The pts/X bit relates to the virtual terminal that the session is attached so...

```
dermot@porkboy:~$ who
dermot   pts/0        2011-08-29 21:32 (williams-mb.local)
dermot   pts/1        2011-08-30 10:52 (192.168.253.109)
```

... gives us some idea which session is which. So if I wanted to kill the session from my MacBook I'd 'kill -9 2522'.

Comment: +1 for `who` command. Forgot it absolutely. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However it seems that the server is not restarting. I've disallowed root ssh access (and so need to restart the service for changes to take effect), and after attempting to restart, I am still able to ssh in as root

Comment: Can you give us the output of '[/etc/init.d/|service] ssh restart'? Also, stoopid question but are you editing sshd_config or ssh_config?

Comment: editing the sshd_config file. Output was:`bash: [/etc/init.d/: No such file or directory
bash: service]: command not found`

Comment: Chris, Dermot wrote this way because he wanted to give both variants in one phrase. Enter either "/etc/init.d/ssh restart" or "service ssh restart" and paste the output.

Comment: Sorry, I should have just written it both ways :(

Comment: It's ok, I have previously tried both ways so thought he might have something I hadnt tried haha

Comment: Thanks for the comment about it not kicking you out of your session! I kept waiting for it to disconnect me so I could verify that it worked. Service ssh restart did the trick

Answer (score 1):

When you restart SSH daemon with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

or

```
service ssh restart
```

the listening daemon restarts with new configuration options (I assume, you restart it for the new config take effect). All sessions already open remain running with old configuration.
To learn, which of ssh sessions is yours, try to execute:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(ssh|PID)'
```

You will get one */usr/sbin/sshd* with PPID 1 and UID *root*. This is the listening daemon. All other *sshd: user@pts/0* records are user sessions. Look for appropriate session by username and kill the process to terminate this session.

I would recomend to do all this in *GNU screen* session, so if you make a mistake, you will be able to reconnect and reattach this *screen* session.

Or I didn't understand the question right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which of the `sshd`s belongs to you, it's really easy:

```
$ ps -aef --forest | egrep "(sshd|PID|David Newcomb is ace)"

UID        PID  PPID STIME TTY        TIME CMD
root      1234     1  2018 ?      00:02:13 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     30546  1234 19:54 ?      00:00:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/0
root     32069 30548 20:17 pts/0  00:00:00  |  \_ egrep (sshd|PID|David Newcomb is ace)
root     30692  1234 19:56 ?      00:00:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/1
root     31890  1234 20:16 ?      00:00:00  \_ sshd: root [priv]
sshd     32054 31890 20:16 ?      00:00:00  |   \_ sshd: root [net]
root     31891  1234 20:17 ?      00:00:00  \_ sshd: [accepted]
sshd     32065 31891 20:17 ?      00:00:00      \_ sshd: [net]
```

You are the one running the `egrep` !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I wrote that will terminate all SSH sessions but the current one (the one running the script):

Many thanks to **David Newcomb** and **patrik** for the assistance in creating this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Many thanks to stackoverflow.com user "patrik" for the following
containsElement () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

SKIP_PIDS=()
ALL_PIDS=()
SESSIONS=`sudo ps -aef --forest | egrep "(sshd|__MY_ID__)"`

# Get root PIDs and add them to the skip list
ROOT_PIDS_STR=$(echo "$SESSIONS" | grep 'root' | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/@@@/g' | tr "\n" ' ')
ROOT_PIDS=($ROOT_PIDS_STR)

# Collect root PIDs and add them to the skip list
for LINE in "${ROOT_PIDS[@]}"; do
  LINE=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -E 's/@@@/ /g')
  PID=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
  SKIP_PIDS+=($PID)
done

# Get my PID and add to the skip list
MY_PID=`echo "$SESSIONS" | grep -B 1 '__MY_ID__' | head -n 1 | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
SKIP_PIDS+=($MY_PID)

# Get all PIDs, and only add those that aren't in the skip list
PIDS_STR=$(echo "$SESSIONS" | grep -v '__MY_ID__' | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/@@@/g' | tr "\n" ' ')
LINES=($PIDS_STR)

# Add all non-skip PIDs to the list of processes to kill
for LINE in "${LINES[@]}"; do
  LINE=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -E 's/@@@/ /g')
  PID=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
  containsElement "$PID" "${SKIP_PIDS[@]}"

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ALL_PIDS+=($PID)
  fi
done

# Kill all PIDs not in the skip list
for PID in "${ALL_PIDS[@]}"; do
  sudo kill -15 "$PID"
done
```